# what does $this->variable mean

Tags: php

```
$this->var
```

There's a "->" symbol when we call a variable, and i'd like to know what actually does the "->" means. I tried to do some research but the textbook and the internet don't explain this clealy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't mind u rate me down but give me a link at least, i seek for knowledge

Comment: Your link is at the top under: *This question already has an answer here:*

Answer (score 0):

PHP has two Object Operator namely -> and ::

-> is used when you are trying to call a method on an Instance and / or access an Instance property.

:: is used when you want to call a static method or call a parent class's version of a method within a child class.